# Simple java snap with jre dependency

Tags: snap

Dear snap[craft] experts,

I am creating a simple snap for a java application:

```
name: freeplane-snap
version: 1.5.18-1
summary: Java program for working with Mind Maps
description: ...
confinement: devmode
grade: stable

apps:
  freeplane-snap:
    command: ./freeplane.sh

parts:
  main:
    plugin: dump
    source: freeplane-1.5.18/
    stage-packages: [openjdk-8-jre]
    filesets:
      mybuild:
        - "*"
    stage:
      - $mybuild
    snap:
      - $mybuild
```

Freeplane uses a gradle build system, but the snapcraft gradle plugin is
not powerful enough (expects "gradlew" to be there and not "gradle", and is
used for single jar projects, i.e. always with 'jar' option). Where can I
submit feature requests / patches for this?

So I am using the project's binary distribution (unzipped to
./freeplane-1.5.18) with the 'dump' plugin, which works well.  However,
since I'm not using a java build system, the jre is missing in the snap
(when running "freeplane-snap" I get an error that the JDK cannot be found,
NOT when running freeplane.sh directly). I tried to add it with
'stage-packages: [openjdk-8-jre]' but this did not help.

Could you please tell me how to add the jre to the mix?

One more question: Hearing about this containment stuff, is it
possible/feasible (using plugs?) to to create a desktop application that
can read and write (mind maps) from/to everywhere, just like a normal .deb?
(like plugs: [network, home]?)

Many Thanks and Best Regards,
Felix

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to use the JDK, not the JRE.  This is to include the awt/viz library dependencies for GUIs
2. You will need to add in the appropriate plugs for visualization (at least X11).
3. You may need a better wrapper or to alter the included script.

   1. Java's user.home property isn't set properly.
   2. The font config data isn't set properly.

Here is an example of my maven project:
https://github.com/ZenHarbinger/torgo

To build from source, open up an Issue and LaunchPad bug.  I wrote the gradlew plugin, but I am not a gradle user.

---

EDIT: Added working files

Here's a snap + wrapper that seems to work.
It's really messy as it copies the contents of freeplane twice.
https://gist.github.com/ZenHarbinger/cf3aec2d7c6110ab0a0780b315cadc2f

---

EDIT 2:
I have submitted an update to the gradle plugin in snapcraft.  It will automatically detect if gradlew exists and also provides the ability to specify the output dir.
Here is freeplane with snapcraft (if you have an updated plugin).
https://github.com/ZenHarbinger/freeplane